# Getting intersection of a keys of a map

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, dictionary

This is my map

```
Map<String,Set<Integer>> transactions = new HashMap<String,Set<Integer>>();
```

This is the Set of string

```
Set<String> check_set
```

Now question is how to make this method

```
Set<Integer> getIntersection(Map<String,Set<Integer>> transactions, Set<String> check_set)
```

Which will return intersection of all the Set of integers corresponding to the keys in check_set.

If the MAP is

```
tea=[1,3,5,7,9], 
milk=[2,3,6,7,9], 
sugar=[1,4,6,8,9]...
```

and if check_set is `{"tea","milk"}` then the method should return values which are present in both tea and milk i.e `{3,7,9}`. Or if it has `{"milk","sugar"}` then it should return `{6,9}`. if it has all three `{"sugar","milk",tea"}` then it should return `{3,9}`.

I understand I need to use `retainAll` function to get intersection. But how to formulate a logic to check all sets of integer in map and get their intersection.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: what about using http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29

Comment: I am confused how to start with this problem. I thought of using an iterator for Set of strings and then checking in map but its not proper.

Comment: Sets.SetView() will give intersection which is same as using in a temporary set in retainAll(). but I check_set can have more than 2 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : **must** use a copy of the first set in map (thanks to Bohemian)

In pseudo-code, you could have

```
Init result set to null to know it is still not initialized

Loop for each key in check_set
    if result is null then result = map{key} // take first set
    else result = intersection(result, map{key}) // and keep on intersecting
```

That gives in java

```
Set<Integer> result = null;
for (String key: check_set) {
    if (result == null) {
        result = new HashSet<Integer>(map.get(key));
    }
    else {
        result.retainAll(map.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, except I would create a new Set rather than use the Map's value, because a) the Map's value may be an unmodifiable set, and b) you will mutate the Map - an unexpected and unwanted side effect.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> private static Set<Integer> getIntersection(Map<String, Set<Integer>> transactions, Set<String> checkSet) {
>     Iterator<String> iterator = checkSet.iterator();
>     // create a copy of the original set
>     Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>(transactions.get(iterator.next()));
>     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
>         result.retainAll(transactions.get(iterator.next()));
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```